# Change row value based on another column in DataFrame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace the values of two columns based on another column in DataFrame. I would like to use dplyr. The example of DataFrame is:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c'),
                 col2 = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12),
                 col3 = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30))
df
```

I want to multiply col2 and col3 by 10 if col1 = 'b' and col2 and col 3 by 20 if col1 = 'c'.

The desired output should be as the following:

```
      col1     col2     col3
1      a        2        5
2      b        40       100
3      a        6        15
4      c        160      400
5      b        100      250
6      c        240      600
```

I tried:

```
df %>% filter(., col1=='b') %>% mutate(.= replace(., col2, col2*10)) %>% mutate(.= replace(., col3, col3*10))
df %>% filter(., col1=='c') %>% mutate(.= replace(., col2, col2*20)) %>% mutate(.= replace(., col3, col3*20))
```

The output is:

```
Error in replace(., col2, col2*10): object 'col2' not found
```

I also tried:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(col2, col3), funs(ifelse(col1=='b', col2*10, col3*10))
df %>% mutate_at(vars(col2, col3), funs(ifelse(col1=='c', col2*20, col3*20))
```

I got an error again:

```
funs() is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0 ...
```

Can anyone help please?
Thank you :)

Comment: The deprecation message is not an error.

Comment: Oh OK I didn't know that. Thank you Axeman!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `filter`ing and then joining we can directly use `mutate_at` with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(col2, col3), ~ 
       case_when(col1 == 'b' ~  .* 10, col1  == 'c' ~ .* 20, TRUE  ~ .))
#  col1 col2 col3
#1    a    2    5
#2    b   40  100
#3    a    6   15
#4    c  160  400
#5    b  100  250
#6    c  240  600
```

---

Or in the `dplyr` 1.0.0, it can be done with `mutate/across`

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(c(col2, col3), ~ 
       case_when(col1 == 'b' ~  .* 10, col1  == 'c' ~ .* 20, TRUE  ~ .)))
#  col1 col2 col3
#1    a    2    5
#2    b   40  100
#3    a    6   15
#4    c  160  400
#5    b  100  250
#6    c  240  600
```

Comment: I haven't really looked much at the recent updates, but can this now also be done with `mutate` and `across`?

Comment: Yeah, just one mutate call with `mutate(across(c(col2, col3), ~...`

Comment: Thank you very much Akrun, Axeman and caldwellst. I truly appreciate you all help. :)

Comment: What's the purpose of TRUE ~ . ?

Comment: @AminShn that is the default case.  Here, `.` is the original column value i.e. if none of the conditions are met, return the column